# Delete Primary Key Entry From Database

Tags: mysql, primary-key

I'm in the process of migrating a site to WordPress. However, the old site is remaining active. The last claimed ID when I did the import was 271. A user submitted a post to the old site and this claimed the ID 272. However, I had posted a test post on the new site which claimed ID 272. So now, when I try to import the most recent post from the old site (even though I **deleted** my test post) it claims that the ID 272 is occupied. ***Is there a way to delete this from the new site so that I can import it?***

The reason they need to match is because I plan on having the old site redirect to the new site, and so the ID would need to match (otherwise I'd end up guessing if I let them all get out of sync).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
DELETE FROM YourTable
WHERE id = 272
```

Replace `YourTable` and `id` with the actual table and column names from your database.

Comment: Thanks. It turns out I never actually deleted the entry from my database, but I thought I did (so I thought the key was occupied even though I deleted the entry), so all it takes is deleting it.

Answer (score 1):

If the tables are created with Engine=InnoDB, the answer that Barmar said is right.

This is true for InnoDB if and only if FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS = 1; otherwise a DELETE from the parent table will not remove rows from the child table,  that reference a row removed from the parent table.

So **be careful** before you delete something. If you want to see which engine the table uses, type:
`SHOW CREATE TABLE TABLE_NAME`